# How to write a namespace in an Element with XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I'm changing my code from vbs to C#, but i have a problem with XMLwriter, how to use XML write to get such output in XML.file :  ??

I have code like this :

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Form1.systemDrive + "\\unattend.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
    writer.WriteStartElement("unattend");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend"); // <<<<<<< Gives an error
```

....

Comment: could you provide expected output? and what error do you get?

Comment: You need to [use a different overload of WriteAttributeString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z46xs1(v=vs.110).aspx) to write a namespace declaration.

Comment: "An error" is always a good description of the error you get... :-/ It's just like "Doesn't work".

Comment: OK error is like "Cannot be redefined "from" to within the same start element Tag" and i would like to get output like this : <unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to put the unattend tag into the given namespace, don't use the `WriteAttributeString` at all and just use

```
writer.WriteStartElement("unattend","urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend");
```

If the namespace was assigned to a prefix, it will use the prefix, otherwise it will generate the necessary xmlns clause.

Also, the `WriteStartDocument` is redundant with the `WriteProcessingInstruction`. Both produce the same output, but you can only have one processing instruction, so you can use either one but not both.