# How do I add a default namespace with no prefix using XMLWriter

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I have to produce an xml document that starts like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeneticsTestReport SchemaVersion="1-4" xmlns="http://www.organdonation.nhs.uk/XMLschema/DCERT/ns" >
```

The above fragment was taken from a file supplied to me and is how the recipient insists it should start.

I have the following code that outputs everything but the xmlns attribute:-

```
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, settings))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("GeneticsTestReport");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("SchemaVersion", SchemaVersion);
            ...other code omitted for brevity
        }
```

I've tried numerous ways of adding the xmlns attribute but I can't get anything to work.

Code such as:-

```
writer.WriteStartAttribute("xmlns", ns);
or
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns","", null, ns);
```

give rise to the exceptions:-

"The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://www.organdonation.nhs.uk/XMLschema/DCERT/ns' within the same start element tag."

or

"Prefix "xmlns" is reserved for use by XML."

In the code above ns is a variable set to "http://www.organdonation.nhs.uk/XMLschema/DCERT/ns"

I have the rest of the document written but cannot solve this xmlns issue.
I am not an xml expert in any way shape or form so would appreciate any assistance that can be provided.

Comment: You may want to start with fixing your `WriteStartElement` call (which should I believe resolve the issue).

Comment: Does [How to write a namespace in an Element with XmlWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35783636/3744182) answer your question?  As indicated in the answer you need to start writing the element `GeneticsTestReport` in the required namespace, i.e. `writer.WriteStartElement("GeneticsTestReport", "http://www.organdonation.nhs.uk/XMLschema/DCERT/ns")`

Comment: Then, to make `"http://www.organdonation.nhs.uk/XMLschema/DCERT/ns"` be the default namespace, use the answer from [XmlWriter won't generate the namespaces I need correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51866408): `writer .WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.organdonation.nhs.uk/XMLschema/DCERT/ns");`  In fact I think your question is a duplicate of those two, agree?

Comment: Yes, `writer.WriteStartElement("GeneticsTestReport", ns);` plus `writer .WriteAttributeString("xmlns", ns);` generates the required XML, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/g6MbLQ.  Closing as a duplicate.

Comment: Many thanks for your replies.
@Alexei gave me the clue to look again at WriteStartElement and I realised then what was wrong although I could have sworn that I'd tried that some time back.

Comment: @dbc - I did search for any previous questions but didn't come across the one you mentioned